# Run pages of my site in background?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pageload

Is there a way to run pages of my website "behind the scenes" when a user visits the landing page?

I have a site that works like this:

There are 3 stages. 
Stage 1 is the landing, Stage 2 is the next layer, Stage 3 is the final layer.

The problem I'm having is:
When a Stage 3 page is loaded, it updates an excel sheet to be parsed and populate things in Stage 2 pages and Stage 1 pages.

So, this is why I'd like to be able to load the Stage 3 pages when the user views the site.

Hope that makes sense. Any way to do this?

Was thinking I could do a bunch of redirects of the Stage 3 pages like a for loop, but this would really suck for the user on bad connection

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: Move the code to a common function and call it from both pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all your stage and excel stuff in a backgroundworker like shown here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Then listen to the events of the backgroundworker (update, and finished) and you can go on from there.

Comment: The link above was for the silverlight backgroundworker, here's the one for the .net native backgroundworker class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx :)